# python socket io client emit got an unexpected keyword argument 'wait'

Tags: linux, python, vps, websocket

I am using RPI, VPS, and socket io. I want to create a website where a user can go to click a button and get a pic from the pi.
I wrote the server and the client applications in python.
the server uses socketio + flask

server.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, rooms, join_room, leave_room

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
sio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Serve the client-side application."""
    with open('index.html') as f:
        return f.read()
    # return app.send_static_file('index.html')

@sio.on('connect')
def connect():
    print('Connected:')

@sio.on('join')
def on_join(room):
    join_room(room)
    print(request.sid + ' joined room ' + room )

@sio.on('leave')
def on_leave(room):
    leave_room(room)
    print(request.sid + ' left room ' + room )

@sio.on('message')
def handle_json(message):
    # print('Received json: ')
    # print(message)
    room = rooms(request.sid)[0]
    print('Forwarding to room:', room)
    sio.send(message, room=room, skip_sid=request.sid, json=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sio.run(app, host= "142.11.210.25", port = 80)
```

rpi_client.py

```
import io
import time

import picamera
import socketio
import base64

sio = socketio.Client()

# Specify the room
room = 'cam_1'
socket_url = 'http://142.11.210.25:80/'

def capture_b64_image():
    # Create an in-memory stream
    image_stream = io.BytesIO()

    # Capture image
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        # Camera warm-up time
        time.sleep(2)
        camera.capture(image_stream, 'jpeg')

    # Encode the image
    image_bytes = image_stream.getvalue()   
    return base64.b64encode(image_bytes).decode()


@sio.on('connect')
def on_connect():
    print('Connection established')
    sio.emit('join', room)

@sio.on('json')
def on_message(data):
    print('Received message:', data)

    encoded_image = capture_b64_image()

    print( len(encoded_image) )
    sio.send({'image': encoded_image})


@sio.on('disconnect')
def on_disconnect():
    print('Disconnected from server')

sio.connect(socket_url)
sio.wait()
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SocketIO Demo</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img id="image-preview" src="" />

        <button id='cam_click'>Take photo</button>

        <script
            src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io('/');
            var room = 'cam_1';

            function bytes2ascii(bytes) {
                var str = '';
                for(var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                    str += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
                }

                return str;
            }

            socket.on('connect', function() {
                console.log(11);
                socket.emit('join', room);
            });

            socket.on('json', function (data) {
                console.log('Received:');
                console.log(data);
                // $('#cam_content').html(data.image);

                //var encoded_image = bytes2ascii(new Uint8Array(data.image) );
                var encoded_image = data.image

                $('#image-preview').attr('src', `data:image/png;base64,${encoded_image}`);

            });

            $(document).ready(function() {
                console.log('Ready...');
                $('#cam_click').click(function() {
                    socket.send('image');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i run the server and the rpi client, I get connection established, and when I click on the button to take photo in the index.html, the server fowrards to room1 and I get that on the rpi client and it takes a pic, but then it crashes when its sending the pic and it gives me 
TypeError: emit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wait'

here is the error I get(rpi client) when I run the codes.

```
Connection established
Received message: image
996008
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/socketio/client.py", line 514, in _handle_eio_message
    self._handle_event(pkt.namespace, pkt.id, pkt.data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/socketio/client.py", line 413, in _handle_event
    r = self._trigger_event(data[0], namespace, *data[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/socketio/client.py", line 455, in _trigger_event
    return self.handlers[namespace][event](*args)
  File "rpi_client2.py", line 41, in on_message
    sio.send({'image': encoded_image})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/socketio/client.py", line 296, in send
    callback=callback, wait=wait, timeout=timeout)
TypeError: emit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wait'
```

I installed python-socketio[client] as instructed.

What could be causing the error  and whats the workaround? thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

According to the python-socketio doc, https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html#emitting-events:

For convenience, a send() method is also provided. This method accepts a data element as its only argument, and emits the standard message event with it:

sio.send('some data')

Therefore, you can change:

sio.send({'image': encoded_image})

to:

sio.emit('message', {'image': encoded_image})